# Cannot deploy by Truffle to Polygon Mumbai testnet

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment, polygon

I`m trying to deploy by truffle to testnet polygon Mumbai a smart contract ,
However it does not work with my contract.

It worked with another smaller contract , but with this one which imports different libraries it doesnt work .

I added the errors below :

Any ideas ?

```
Compiling your contracts…

    Compiling .\contracts\TenesseERC20.sol
    Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IERC20.sol
    Compiling .\contracts\libraries\Address.sol
    Compiling .\contracts\libraries\Counters.sol
    Compiling .\contracts\libraries\SafeMath.sol
    Compiling .\contracts\types\ERC20.sol
    Compiling .\contracts\types\Ownable.sol
    Artifacts written to C:\Users\John\polygon-truffle\build\contracts
    Compiled successfully using:

    solc: 0.7.5+commit.eb77ed08.Emscripten.clang

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
code: -32603,

message: ‘Too Many Requests’,

data: { originalError: {} }
})

at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)

at Web3ProviderEngine.emit (events.js:389:17)

at C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:54:14
at afterRequest (C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:148:21)

at C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:174:21

at C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:232:9


at C:\Users\John\node_modules\async\internal\once.js:12:16

at replenish (C:\Users\John\node_modules\async\internal\eachOfLimit.js:61:25)

at C:\Users\John\node_modules\async\internal\eachOfLimit.js:71:9

at eachLimit (C:\Users\John\node_modules\async\eachLimit.js:43:36)

at C:\Users\John\node_modules\async\internal\doLimit.js:9:16

at end (C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\index.js:211:5)
at C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\rpc.js:52:18

at Request._callback (C:\Users\John\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\rpc.js:53:11)

at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\John\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)

at Request.emit (events.js:400:28)
```

Comment: What are you doing in the truffle-config and deploy scripts? From the error message the network isn't correctly configured or you IP was blacklisted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which node do you use to connect to Polygon Mumbai?
https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com is known to have request limits.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to add the following configuration in your `truffle-config.js` file, under the `networks` section:

```
  pollingInterval: 1800000,
  disableConfirmationListener: true
```

This is how it should look like:

```
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    matic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(privateKey, "YOUR_RPC"),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true,
      networkCheckTimeout: 9000000,
      pollingInterval: 1800000,
      disableConfirmationListener: true
    }
```

You can also refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBQnkHSiPQ8) for a more visual explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is because of the RPC used. Generally, everyone uses public RPCs and they cannot handle this many requests coming from different users at the same time. Deployment is smooth if u purchase a private RPC from services like alchemy, quicknode, etc.